# TeeChart Title Wrapping

Tags: activex, teechart

can we wrap the Title of Chart reduce the chart Height.In My case user can shrink the chart area the issus is since we are not wrapping the chart title most of space is utilized by it.

Thanks
Akshay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand your exact problem. You could try not displaying the title and use an Annotation tool instead, which won't affect chart's size. If this doesn't help please send us a simple example project we can run "as-is" to reproduce the problem here and provide more detailed information on the issue.